# What is the shortcut key to move from one tab to another tab in Gedit?

Tags: editor, gedit

There are multiple files openned with gedit.

Is there any shortcut key to move from one tab to another tab ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+PgUp goes to the previous tab. Ctrl+Alt+PgDn goes to the next tab.

If this does not work, see the Documents menu.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this  "Jump to nth tab <kbd>Alt+ n</kbd>". It works fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

Ctrl+Shift+Tab should switch between tabs.

Comment: You are talking about gedit, the text editor for Gnome desktop?  That doesn't seem to do it.  I have gedit v. 2.30.3, released in 2010.